# Size limits on POST

Tags: php, linux

I was running approximately PHP Version 5.3.5.  I wanted to enable SOAP, and upgraded to PHP Version 5.3.13 using webtatic repo.  Everything is working great!  Except...

I POST some an array using Ajax.  The full array is posted by the client, but it appears the server only receives the first 1,000 elements of the array.

I looked into php.ini, and can't see any limit.

Please advise.

Comment: Most probably you hit a limit in PHP, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9673895/php-warning-unknown-input-variables-exceeded-1000 (if so, there should be a warnign in your logs)

Comment: Feel kind of silly.  Can't find the error log.  Currently, I am not in production, and just display them.

Comment: When using Apache, check the main error_log - you might need root access on linux. Other than that, try to increase the config setting from the linked answer.

Comment: I had been looking into /var/log/httpd/error.log.  It is huge!  I changed the name and made a new blank one, but am doing something wrong since Apache isn't updating it.

Comment: Quite off-topic, but apache only writes to the new log after restarting. To see the end of the file, use `tail /var/log/httpd/error.log` ; )

Comment: Yep, figured out tail.  And found Unknown: Input variables exceeded 1000. To increase the limit change max_input_vars in php.ini. just as you suggested!

Comment: Thank you!  max_input_vars=4000

Comment: Please add an answer stating to change max_input_vars so I my select it as being the right answer.  Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I flagged this as a duplicate of [PHP Warning: Unknown: Input variables exceeded 1000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9673895/php-warning-unknown-input-variables-exceeded-1000?lq=1) but the OP there had a different problem. Thus here the solution from the comments:

When PHP 5.3.9+ returns exactly 1000 variables and / or array elements, you run into security limit, see [php.ini:max-input-vars](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars). PHP Versions before that can run into the same problem caused by a similar limit imposed by suhosin, see [its config](http://www.hardened-php.net/suhosin/configuration.htm)

Increase the limit or change the way you transfer the data.

Comment: Thank you.  That one had me stumped!

Comment: I had this same problem today and I didnt want to increase the value from max-input-vars. So, I used a jquery to .serialize() the form and sent only one input with this big string to php. After that I tried json_decode/parse_str and other JSON libs, all without success. Then, I tried mb_parse_str() and it worked. Original form had 3960 inputs of tabular data (mostly hidden).

Answer (score 1):

In php.ini there is the following configuration directive:

```
; Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept.
; http://php.net/post-max-size
post_max_size = 8M
```

Comment: It was already set at 8M.  Changed it to 10M just for kicks and restarted Apache, but no change.

Answer (score 1):

In php.ini look for

```
post_max_size = 10M
```

Answer (score 0):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/208427 says IE has limits of about 2k, I do remember HTML has some limits but I thought the HTML limit was on get not post.