# phpMyAdmin takes forever to show big table: Input variables exceeded 1000

Tags: php, mysql, select, phpmyadmin

I have a MySQL Table with 31 Columns and A few hundred rows. When I want to look at the table in phpMyAdmin (`SELECT * FROM the_table` in phpmyadmin), it displays "loading" for several minutes, before eventually showing me the table. Weird is, that PhpMyAdmin also says that the query was executed in 0.002 seconds.

Shortly before finishing loading, phpMyAdmin displays a tiny error message that the `Input variables exceeded 1000` - Why is that so?

Comment: What's the load on the server look like?  MySQL Workbench may be a better GUI than PHPMyAdmin when trying to view tens of thousands of fields.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9673895/php-warning-unknown-input-variables-exceeded-1000

Comment: @Devon The MySQL server runs on my computer. Going to look into that workbench.

Comment: @PrestaShop-Developer.com The problems are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should go for some desktop based mysql clients like Heidi and SQLYog. There are certain limitations with phpmyadmin since you are accessing mysql via browser, if the query is taking too much time, you browser would discard the request because of the time out.

I would recommend you to go through http://www.heidisql.com/ or sql yog. They are very fast and in use since last few years.

Comment: let me know if you need any help @Fly. You will need to add hostname as 127.0.0.1, database username and password.. port would be 3306 and that is all.. it is very easy to use and you would love the speed since you have been working on web based which is pretty slow..